# Can i enter Norway with Iceland visa when it wasn't in my itinerary

Tags: air-travel

I received an Iceland visa but as of now i have got a feeling of also  reaching Norway though i didn't include it in my itinerary as a second country to visit. Can this cause me problems at Norway borders since it is not in my itinerary??

Comment: Yes, the nordics have a special agreement, besides Schengen. You barely even need any ID to travel between those countries.